# CodeIgniter doesn't load upload library

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-form-helper

I'm having a problem with loading a CodeIgniter library,

I've already built three (3) websites with CodeIgniter, so I consider myself familiar with this framework.

The problem is only with the upload lib. I've tried with multiple functions and it still doesn't work.

I've even tried with [the CodeIgniter example](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)

In google I can't find any answers, does anyone have an idea what it could be?

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->library('v');
    $this->load->model('admin_model');
}

public function upload_a_thing($set = null){
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    if(!$set){
        $this->load->view('admin/upload_a_thing');
    }else{
        $this->load->library('Upload');
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
        } else {

            $file = $this->upload->data();
            //          $product = $this->admin_model->get_products($id);
            $newFilePath = $config['upload_path'].'try.jpg';
            $file['file_name'] = str_replace(" ","_",$file['file_name']);
            rename($config['upload_path'].$file['file_name'], $newFilePath);
        }   
    }
}
```

### CodeIgniter Error

```
 Undefined property: Admin::$upload
```

### PHP error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function do_upload() on a non-object
```

### Edited for Spary

```
        $config['upload_path'] = './media/imgs/products/';
        $this->load->library('upload',$config);
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
```

Comment: can you share the whole class?

Comment: changed it to the whole function, constructor and class name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your form looks like this:

```
<input type="file" class="input" name="logo"  />
```

then call do_upload() like this:

```
 do_upload('logo');
```

If it looks like this:

```
 <input type="file" class="input" name="userfile" />
```

then call it like this:

```
 do_upload();
```

Comment: this is my input <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

Answer (score 0):

do something like this

```
if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code...

```
$this->load->library('Upload');
```

[As per all examples in the documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html), `upload` should be in all lower-case and most likely the reason the library is not loading.

---

Additionally, if your `$config` array is missing, you're not following the example code in the documentation:

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';   // <- preferences
$this->load->library('upload', $config); // <- load library and set configuration
```

OR

```
$this->load->library('upload');         // <- load library

$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';  // <- preferences
$this->upload->initialize($config);     // <- set configuration
```

OR

```
// 'upload' library is "auto-loaded"    // <- load library

$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';  // <- preferences
$this->upload->initialize($config);     // <- set configuration
```

From the chart of preferences, they all seem optional, except for `upload_path`...

> **Default Value**: None
>   
>   **Description**: The path to the folder where the upload should be placed. The folder must be writable and the path can be absolute or relative.

I'm not sure how CodeIgniter could know where to upload the file when there's no `upload_path` because there is no default and your entire configuration array is missing.

Comment: check the last edit, it doesnt work yet, actualy i copyed this code from another website that ive done, there it was working.

Comment: @EyalAvitan, don't know what else to tell you. Other than where your posted code was broken, this library works for me.  Are you sure you've properly set the permissions on the upload folder?  Are you still getting the same exact error message as before?

Comment: i think i found a hint, ive tryed to load an other lib (that ive created) and i had the same problem, then ive used get_instance function (just to check), and it work. now, im in a controller so i dont really need to use this any chance it help us get the reason it happening (i dont really wanna use get_instance all over my website & i dont wanna leave this error open.) thank you for the help

Comment: @EyalAvitan, No idea how you broke it or what you're now asking me... sounds like a completely different issue than where we started.